# return json success from three levels deep

Tags: php, ajax, oop

I have a setup like below (example code obviously).  The success json is not making it back up the chain to my ajax handler.  Is there a standardized way I should be handling this?

The function is completing its task (inserts into db) but it wont return the success.

```
function handle_ajax_posts() {
    if ($_POST['data'] == 'example')
        $post_data = prepare_data_func($_POST['data']);
        return $post_data;
}

function prepare_data_func($data) {
    $clean = striptags($_POST['data'];
    $send = exampleClass::build($clean);
    return $send;

}

class exampleClass {

    public function build() {
        //do things here
        if (true) 
            return json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) );
        else
            return json_encode( array( 'success' => false ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a static method `$send = exampleClass::build($clean);` and not defined the method as static.

try

```
public static function build() 
{
}
```

Comment: apologies, that is just a typo i made while typing this example.